# Traversing a tree in a special way

Tags: algorithm, ocaml

We have a binary tree

```
type 'a tree = Node of 'a * 'a tree * 'a tree | Null ;;
```

We want to return an `'a list` containing all vertices in a specific order, i.e. the distance between two adjacent vertices in the list may not exceed 3. Each vertex can only appear once.

Example. For the tree

```
      1
     / \
    2   6
   /
  3
 / \
4   5
```

one possible answer is `[1; 3; 4; 5; 2; 6]`

For the time being I have the following code:

```
let walk t =
    let rec pom_walk t acc end_root = (* it's symmetric, so it could be start_root and the result would be correct too *)
        match t with
        | Null -> acc
        | Node (nr, l, r) ->
            if end_root then
                nr::(pom_walk r (pom_walk l acc false) false)
            else
                (pom_walk r (pom_walk l acc true) true) @ [nr]
     in
        pom_walk t [] true
```

but this code has square complexity due to the usage of the `@` operator, which is linear itself.

How can I solve this in linear time?

Comment: your "possible answer" is wrong, 6 - 2 = 4.

Comment: @willywonka_dailyblah In the graph the distance is 2.

Comment: Not familiar with OCaml, but I'm guessing `@` is list append? In Haskell, one common approach is to switch from lists to functions that prepend a list to their input, so that then you can use concatenation (= function composition) at either end efficiently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you're pushing elements at the front *and* the back of the list, it'd be nice to be able to perform both of these operations easily. As @david-eisenstat suggested, you can use [difference lists](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Difference_list).

I present here a different solution. We are going to represent our list by two lists: an initial segment and a (reversed) end one.

```
type 'a init_last = 'a list * 'a list
```

We can make this intuition more formal by giving a function `to_list` turning such an `'a init_last` into the `'a list` it represents:

```
let to_list (xs : 'a init_last) : 'a list =
  let (init, last) = xs in init @ rev last
```

It is now easy to define helper functions defining what an empty `'a init_last` looks like and pushing items on top / at the end of the list represented by our `'a init_last` in constant time:

```
let empty : 'a init_last = ([], [])

let push_top (a : 'a) (xs : 'a init_last) : 'a init_last =
  let (init, last) = xs in (a :: init, last)

let push_end (xs : 'a init_last) (a : 'a) : 'a init_last =
  let (init, last) = xs in (init, a :: last)
```

We can then use these combinators in your definition of `walk` and return a more conventional `'a list` by post-processing the result of `pom_walk` using `to_list`:

```
let walk t =
    let rec pom_walk t acc end_root =
        match t with
        | Null -> acc
        | Node (nr, l, r) ->
            if end_root then
                push_top nr (pom_walk r (pom_walk l acc false) false)
            else
                push_end (pom_walk r (pom_walk l acc true) true) nr
     in
        to_list (pom_walk t empty true)
```

Answer (score 0):

@gallais showed a nice solution, I'd like to share the one I came up with. Please scrutinize it until there's nothing left ;)

```
let walk t =
    let rec pom_walk t cont end_root =
        match t with
        | Null -> cont
        | Node (nr, l, r) ->
            let resL = pom_walk l cont (not end_root) in
            let resR = pom_walk r resL (not end_root) in
                if end_root then
                    function res -> nr::(resR res)
                else
                    function res -> resR (nr::res)
     in
        pom_walk t (fun x -> x) true []
```